# run queries periodically (ala crontab) from a postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replicate (a mininimal) crontab functionality in a postgresql database table with crontab-like semantics as follows below (indices not shown, for simiplicity):

```
create table schedule (
id int not null primary key,
command text
);

create table schedule_detail(
schedule_id int not null references schedule(id),
sd_minute smallint not null,
sd_hour smallint not null,
sd_day smallint not null,
sd_month smallint not null,
sd_year smallint not null,
sd_dayofweek smallint not null
);
```

I have only got as far as the schema design. I would like some ideas on how I can implement this. In particular, how to implement:

1. The 'periodic polling' of the schedule table
2. How to determine which schedule to be run

Does postgresql have any native (inbuilt) functionality that I can build upon to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php) will do the job. A complete setup can be found at [Postgresonline.com](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/19-Setting-up-PgAgent-and-Doing-Scheduled-Backups.html).

Comment: +1 It even uses a uses a [cron-style format](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-schedules.html)

Comment: I decided to 'roll my own' since pgAgent is overkill for what I want. Still, I'll accept this as an answer, because it set me on the right path

Comment: @skyeagle, i would love to see your version of pgAgent, did u make it with pgsql or a different scripting language?

Comment: @Frank Heikens can i schedule some sql command to be executed every 10 minutes ?

Comment: @MrPhi: Yes it can, just mark the 00, 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 minutes checkboxes. Leave the day and hour checkboxes blank and you're done.

Comment: From what I've read so far, it looks like pgAgent is a part of pgAdmin, but not actually a part of the PostgreSQL server itself.  Is this true?  I don't want to leave a machine running so it can execute this query upon the schedule, I want the database server itself to manage this.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using psql + crontab for it. Like this :

This crontab entry will delete content older than 60 days on rolling basis.

```
0 16 * * * PGPASSWORD=mypassword psql -Umyuser -dmyschema -c "delete from mytable where created_at < now() - interval '60 days'"
```